# Can you find an available Class with just a String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to grab the Class object in a call I'm making, but the only place that I can find it is in `params[:controller]`. But this returns a string.

Can I find a Class object with just a string?

Comment: From where are you making the call, and what are you trying to pass as a parameter? If you're in the controller, use `self`. That said, I'm *very* skeptical that passing around a controller is a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) method that you can use to convert the string to an appropriately named constant, which in combination with `const_get` should be what you need. Here a simplified example, I don't have a Rails console available at the moment:

> > ObjectSpace.const_get("array".capitalize).new #=> []

In Rails something like

```
"array".classify.constantize.new
```

should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to class by this way:

```
"class".capitalize.constantize
```

Answer (score 0):

for string to class, you can use string.constantize. But, are you looking for current controller object which is processing request?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it without Rails/ActiveSupport.

```
def constant_from_full_name(name)
  name.split("::").inject(::Object) do |const_so_far, name_fragment|
    const_so_far.const_get(name_fragment)
  end
end

constant_from_full_name("Some::Path::To::My::Class")
```